# Import configuration files during React build

Tags: reactjs, npm-scripts

I have a React App that I would like to customize it during the build stage so each build can be used for a different client and only their config files are bundled into the app.

In `/src` I have a Config.js file and Profile.css file.

```
Config.js
const name = "Dean";
const profilePic = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/dean-1024.png';
const validateTime = (openingTime) => { ... return isValid }
export { name, profilePic, validateTime }

Proile.css
:root {
  --clr-primary: hsl(353, 100%, 41%);
  --clr-accent: hsl(350, 54%, 54%);
  --clr-neutral: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
```

But I want these files moved into another directory (i.e. /configs) so I can run `npm run start -- dean` or `npm run build -- john` and `"scripts": {"prebuild": "some_build_script", .}` will then import the correct configuration files and the built bundle will not include all configuration files.

I would also like it done in a way that git would not see the /src/Config.js has been modified every time I run npm for a different client. But I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve I have modified the `package.json` scripts to run a prepare script. I want to pass arguments to the prepare script so I cannot use `prestart` or `prebuild`.  Now I can run `npm start -- <name>`

```
-- /package.json --
"start": "node prepare.mjs",
"poststart": "react-scripts start",
"build": "node prepare.mjs",
"postbuild": "react-scripts build",
```

The `.gitignore` contains an entry to ignore anything inside the config directory. But because you cannot commit an empty directory I've added .gitkeep.

```
-- /.gitignore --
/src/Configuration/*
/public/*
!.gitkeep
```

The `prepare.mjs` script moves the files in `/configurations/<name>` to `/src/config/`

```
-- /prepare.mjs --
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import * as path from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

// Deletes all files and directories inside the dirPath, returning a promise.
const deleteFiles = async (dirPath) => {
  const list = await fs.readdir(dirPath)
  return Promise.all(list
    .filter(fileName => fileName !== '.gitkeep')
    .map(fileName => {
      const file = path.join(dirPath, fileName)
      return fs.rm(file, {recursive: true})
    })
)}

const client = process.argv[2] || "dean"
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const clientPath = path.join(__dirname, "configurations", client)
const configPath = path.join(__dirname, "src", "config")

// List of all files and directories inside the client's configuration directory
const clientFiles = await fs.readdir(clientPath, {withFileTypes: true})

// copy all of the client's files into the Configuration directory
await deleteFiles(configPath)
await Promise.all(clientFiles
  .filter(dirent => !dirent.isDirectory())
  .map(dirent => {
    const src = path.join(clientPath, dirent.name)
    const dest = path.join(configPath, dirent.name)
    return fs.cp(src, dest)
}))
```

This is not my entire script so you may need to play with it to work. I have also done the same with the public directory. Below is the folder structure

```
/
  - configurations
      - dean
         - Config.js
         - image.png
         - public/
      - john
         - Config.js
         - image.png
         - pubic/
  - src
     - config
        - .gitkeep
     - index.js
  - .gitignore
  - package.json
  - public
     - .gitkeep
```